# Navbar icon bar animation error

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

I have added animated icon bar in bootstrap4 `navbar`. It is working but after clicking the burger icon, the **X** is showing on the left side of the screen but it should be on the right where the burger icon appears

https://jsfiddle.net/Kuntal_nescode/8L98q12r/2/

Comment: Please put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

add `position: relative;` to the  `.navbar-toggler:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {..}` because then the `position: absolute;` you use on the cross `span`'s will be relative on his parrent div

```
 .navbar-toggler:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out @Jeremy

Comment: Good, if this did solve your problem please select this as your answer, or make your own answer with extra info about the problem if you think you could be more informative that way. Have a good day.